# Long delay in IIS using impersonation

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, impersonation, visual-foxpro

We're getting a very weird alternating delay in IIS after migrating to 64bit.

We have a web service (built using AnyCPU and .NET 2.0) referencing a COM EXE built using FoxPro to access MYOB.

The web service is configured to impersonate a specific user account.

Initially we thought the delays we were experiencing were due to reloading the MYOB data (400MB+) over the network repeatedly, so we added in some logging to be sure, and found the following.

1. It seems to delay every second request, with the first request being fast.
2. In the security event log we get event ID 4672 (special privileges) for the account about 1 second after the call is made from the client.
3. X time later we log a call on the first line of the method called (before everything else, including the try/catch)

X may be 2-6 seconds when things are working, and up to 7 minutes when it's not (usually about 80 seconds).

Any suggestions for where I can look for more information or possible causes?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using COM/EXE and not doing directly with .net via Visual Foxpro OleDB?  Its quite fast and can run queries, inserts, updates, deletes, etc with no problems.?  Also, is it a data-entry system, or is it a fixed read-only type of access too.

Comment: Not my choice.  There is a limited supply of MYOB programmers available, and the company we are using can provide the functionality we need this way.  The COM side is basically given a list of IDs (often one) and looks them up in a SQL db to update the MYOB card details or create invoices.